# Books for Solar physics

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, sun, stars

I am thinking about applying for an internship at a university under a professor who does Helioseismology.
What resources would you recommend me for being ready for such an internship?
Can you suggest some good books for the same.

Comment: What's your background? Do you already know something about stellar structure and stellar evolution or you start from zero? I think adding these infos may help people callbrate their answers

Comment: I do have quite a bit of knowledge about solar physics but still nothing as compared to what I presume might be required!

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading recent papers that the professor has published (if you do not have access to journals, I am sure she will be happy to send you copies of her latest papers). Even if you do not fully understand them, they will give you a basis to talk to her about her research.

Then see if she has published any books and read those. Failing that, see if she has published any lecture notes online, or a recommended reading list for any of her courses. Or (and this is the really obvious answer) ask her what material she recommends that you read.